# family visit to attend their first cousin wedding

Tags: bangladesh

my niece and nephew apply for family visit and a gave the sponsorship also said i will bare cost they also submit their documents, however they has been refused under V4.2 a,c of appendix V what i can do now. 
thank you

---

do my first cousin have any right to attend my wedding? if have the right is this under human right or not?

Comment: As posted by o.m. on your answer that should have been a comment: Having relatives attend a wedding is not a human right.

Comment: Could you add what country they were trying to visit? "V4.2 a,c of appendix V" strongly suggests UK, but it should be explicit in the question.

Comment: Consider the couple traveling to their family's home area, and holding a second party or reception for friends and relatives who could not get to the UK. I have been to a reception where the bride wore her wedding dress and there was a cake, but the reception was a couple of weeks after the actual wedding and held in a different city.

Comment: Article 8 covers separation of family members but, as other have commented, having family members attend a wedding isn’t a human right https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/law-and-courts/civil-rights/human-rights/what-rights-are-protected-under-the-human-rights-act/your-right-to-respect-for-private-and-family-life/